# Question of the week #36

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 36 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Comment: Nominations go to answer, please submit your nominee for QOTW as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for catching up on this - I often handle QOTW but have been busy.

Comment: @Sathya, I did not know I was the editor of QOTW. :O

Comment: @iglvzx I didn't either :P

Comment: Looks like Sathya did some copypasta... fixed!

Answer (score 15):

> #### [How much power the system is REALLY consuming?](https://superuser.com/questions/373791/how-much-power-the-system-is-really-consuming)
>
> I suspect that my ATX case's power unit from China provides FAR LESS power than it's supposed to. Is there a way to see (in real time) how much power the whole system is trying to consume and how much is it really getting? Maybe, not in watts, but the voltage is not enough, say, 4.5V instead of 5V. What I really need to know, is should I return the power supply to a shop and buy another one.

Answer (score 11):

> #### [How to store and preserve lots of data?](https://superuser.com/questions/374386/how-to-store-and-preserve-lots-of-data)
>
> I have many DVDs with movies and games, they are getting old and dusty, some of them are damaged. And I have more than 300 GB of general files in my PC. I want to store and preserve all of my data and keep them for a long long time.

Answer (score 10):

> ### [Why does Windows Progress Bar always give such horrible estimates?](https://superuser.com/questions/374548/why-does-windows-progress-bar-always-give-such-horrible-estimates)
>
> I realized this "bug" a long time ago, since Windows 95/98, but it still continues until today, on Windows Seven... The displayed remainder time was on 60 minutes, but the real time was less than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 9):

> #### [Is it possible to use a storage disk (such as a USB drive) as RAM?](https://superuser.com/questions/373484/is-it-possible-to-use-a-storage-disk-such-as-a-usb-drive-as-ram)
>
> My motherboard (HP Pavilion s3000y) only supports 2GB of RAM max. Which means that I can only allocate 1GB for running VMs, and applications that use a lot of RAM are slow (such as games and Visual Studio).
>
> Is it possible to use a storage disk such as a USB drive as RAM?

Answer (score 5):

> #### [What's the use of windows hard disk write cache when the hard drive already has more than 8 megabytes of cache?](https://superuser.com/questions/373045/whats-the-use-of-windows-hard-disk-write-cache-when-the-hard-drive-already-has)
>
> Doesn't a hard drive use its cache with high utilization? I see up to 20MB/s difference on file writes when I disable windows disk write cache. Does anybody know why cache size matters this much?