# Status for "Question of the Week" and related ad on the front page

Tags: discussion, superuser-blog

The front page of SuperUser linked to [this Question-of-the-Week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week) overview with an ad (traced [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3957/community-promotion-ads-2012), I think...). Intrigued by that idea I clicked on the link. It took a little bit before I noticed that the "[newest question of the week](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4012/question-of-the-week-36)" numbered #36 doesn't correspond to "week 36 of this year" but was posted in January 2012.

- Did this "question of the week" thing stop? Why / what happened? (it seems like such a fun idea :D)
- If it stopped for some reason, perhaps the front-page shouldn't promote it anymore?

Comment: If anyone wants to retag this question: please do. Wasn't sure whether "discussion" was the right tag, and was also in doubt whether adding "question-of-the-week" was a good idea...

Comment: it's not stopped as such - contributions/contributors dried up

Comment: Feel free to write a draft if you see something awesome that we could feature on the blog

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Did this "question of the week" thing stop? Why / what happened? (it seems like such a fun idea :D)

The moderator in question still attends school and I believe some work kept him from following up on the QotW questions, you can [see the dates](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week?sort=newest&pagesize=15) go from a weekly schedule to a bi-weekly to even monthly schedule over time.

It is also not only about following up these questions, but also about writing up the blog post in proper format. Not to forget that he is a moderator which is around on the website, chat and other things that keep Super User a busy activity for him.

So, it's not like that something bad happened or turned out to be a bad idea; it's just a matter of time...

> If it stopped for some reason, perhaps the front-page shouldn't promote it anymore?

Indeed, I have [temporarily changed](https://meta.superuser.com/a/3963/9666) the ad to one of previous time. I think honestly that we should be promoting [writing things for the blog](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/09/are-you-interested-in-writing-for-our-blog/), as well as getting [more activity in our Super User Blog Editor room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/356/super-user-blog-editor-room); but that would require someone to make a community ad for that. But attempts at that have not yieleded many writers thus far

[Bringing the blog into the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110998/using-the-stack-engine-for-the-blog-a-long-term-idea-for-maintaining-a-healthy) is something that could solve that, which we are patiently waiting for...

Comment: Yep. Tom is correct in stating that I am alive, but haven't had time for QotW lately. Anybody who wants to take this on going forward, let me know. I'll get you all set up.

Comment: Okay that's cool, thanks for taking the time to answer! And @nhinkle good to hear you're alive and well, doing important stuff on and off SU :)